# App in release mode does not build and gives linkassemlies error for JsonReaderWriterFactory

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

When I am trying to build my app in Release mode I am getting the following error:

```
The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReaderWriterFactory::CreateJsonReader(System.IO.Stream,System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas)' (defined in 'SyncCacheControllerMD, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'SyncCacheControllerMD, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved.
   at Xamarin.Android.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, String message, Object[] args)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() AcclaimAndroidApp
```

I tried the following:

1. changed Linking to sdk and other Assemblies.
2. uninstalled and installed whole xamarin again
3. tried to use the latest version of Newtonsoft.json dll which is build against monodroid.
4. searched extensively on search engines.

After all this I still cannot find a solution for this. My apk in debug mode is not getting installed on devices which is not developer enabled.